# Not getting proper date in text view using android

Tags: java, android, program-entry-point

I have two button 1st is next and other is previous. i want to show a date as date of month of year in text view. the date should be seeing in text view is 1st day of that week.

While pressing next button it must show next week 1st day of starting of that week while pressing previous button it must show previous week 1st day of starting of that week.

the code is following .

I am fresher in android.

```
package com.example.child;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button bn;
    Button bp;
     Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
       int w = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button bp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



         c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
         SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
            String printDate = mDF.format(c.getTime());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
            String printDate2 = mDF.format(c.getTime());

            System.out.println(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
           ed .setText(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);


        bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                w++;

                String ss=g(w);
                ed.setText(ss);

            }

            private String g(int weekfromtoday) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println(""+weekfromtoday);

                Calendar m=Calendar.getInstance();
                m.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,m.SUNDAY);
                m.set(m.DAY_OF_YEAR,m.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+weekfromtoday);
                m.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,+6);
            SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
            String p=s.format(m.getTime());
        System.out.println(p);
         m.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
            String printDate2 = s.format(m.getTime());
            ed.setText(""+printDate2);
            return p + " >> " + printDate2; 



            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need help then ask some question. What is your problem?

Comment: @Szamot my question is  i want to show a date as dd-mm-yyyy in edit text. the date should be 1st day of that week. while pressing next button it must show next week 1st date and while press previous it should be show previous week. this my question

Comment: That's not the question, that's look like you want to somebody write your code for you. You have to told what is your problem, in which place your code doesn't work. Then we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : have a global calendar object:

```
private Calendar calendar;
```

Step 2 : Function to get the beginning of next week:

```
public void getNextWeek() {
        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        String dateString = getFormattedDate(calendar);

    }
```

Step 3 : Function to get the beginning of previous week:

```
public void getPreviousWeek() {
            calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
            String dateString = getFormattedDate(calendar);

        }
```

function to convert calendar object to String:

```
 public String getFormattedDate(Calendar cal){
          SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
          String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
          return formatted;
    }
```

Comment: your answer is working but when looking to months it is showing as a current min eg(12-54-2015). expecting you got my content. it is not showing month.